# Jquery. Меняю цвет div, а он сразу меняется обратно

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть главная страница, на ней выводится 5 записей, и внизу есть переключатели на другие страницы где будут выводиться другие 5 записей.
Таких переключателей в виде кнопок 114 штук.
Генерируются они кодом:

```html
for ($x=1;$x<=($num_rows)/5+1;$x++)
                 echo "<div  id='foot'><a href='?page=".$x."' class='col' style='text-decoration:none;color:black'>".$x."</a></div>"
```

Где $x - номер текущей страницы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы при нажатии, на div с ссылкой на страницу цвет div'a менялся
пока я на ней нахожусь.
Я делаю это так:

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.col').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color','darkmagenta');
            $(this).css('color','red');
    })

})
</script>
```

Все вроде бы ничего, но цвет меняется всего лишь на долю секунды, а потом обратно возвращается в исходное состояние.
Вот CSS file:

```css
*
{margin:0;
    padding:0}

div
{
    font-family: Calibri;
}
h1
{
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
body
{
    height: 100%;
}
#content
{
    height: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;

}
#footer
{
    width:98%;
    height:150px;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    background-color:white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:15px;
}
#page
{border-top-style: dotted;
    border-top-width: thin;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.announce
{
    font-size:17px;
}
#foot
{   background-color:#dfe7ff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:grey;
    border-width: thin;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Calibri Light";
    font-size: 15px;
    width:35px;
    height:17px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#foot:hover
{
    background-color: darkmagenta;
    color: white;
}

span.date
{
    background-color: darkmagenta;
    color: white;
    font-family:Calibri;
    margin:3px 8px 0 0;
}
.title
{
    font-size: 20px;
}
.col
{
    display: block;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы он менялся на все время, пока я нахожусь на странице.

Comment: так вы же переходите на другую страницу, весь рендер заново отрабатывает, стоит добавить css класс типа `active` или `selected`, который выставлять из php

Comment: создавать в цикле множество дивов с одинаковым id - плохо

Comment: проще сделать в php коде проверку, если страница активна, дать номерку страницы классс, а в css - цвет этого класса красный.

Comment: я еще не уверен что у вас нумерация правильно строится, либо вы так и задумывали выводить лишь пятую часть ссылок?

Comment: У меня 566 записей в таблице, я вывовожу на каждой странице по 5 записей. Поэтому номеров 114.

Comment: Jean-Claude, а как это правильно сделать (сделать в php коде проверку, если страница активна, дать номерку страницы класс)?

Comment: @soloway0000, ну вы же как-то организуете вывод определённой серии записей, значит, вам известен номер текущей коллекции? Вот его сравнивайте с `$x` и при совпадении устанавливайте диву класс `active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем class active если страница активна:

```
for ($x=1;$x<=($num_rows)/5+1;$x++) {
    if($x == $pg){
        echo "<div  class='foot' id='".$x."'><a href='?page=".$x."' class='col active' style='text-decoration:none;color:black'>".$x."</a></div>"
    } else {
        echo "<div  class='foot' id='".$x."'><a href='?page=".$x."' class='col' style='text-decoration:none;color:black'>".$x."</a></div>"
    }
}
```

В css добавьте:

```
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Или так:

```
for ($x=1;$x<=($num_rows)/5+1;$x++) {
    $active_class = '';
    if($x == $pg) {
       $active_class = ' active'
    }

    echo "<div  class='foot' id='".$x."'><a href='?page=".$x."' class='col" . $active_class . "' style='text-decoration:none;color:black'>".$x."</a></div>"
}
```

Comment: второй вариант однозначно удобнее :)

Comment: Спасибо, вы еще не успели выложить второй способ, я уже сделал по первому и все заработало. Я однозначно намотаю себе на ус это и больше не буду задавать глупых вопросов. Благодарю!

Answer (score -1):

Так как я новичок для меня это сложновато, если кто умеет. Модифицируйте.Спасибо!

```html
<?php include_once "connection.php"?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Новости</h1>
<div id="content">
    <?php //Узнаю текущую страницу

         if (isset($_GET['page']))
           {
              if ($_GET['page']==null)
                 $pg=1;
              else
                 $pg=$_GET['page'];
           }
         else
           {
                 $pg=1;
           }

         //Вывожу 5 записей
         if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY idate LIMIT ".(5*($pg-1)).",5"))
           {
               while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                  {
                     echo "<br>";
                     echo "<span class='date'>".gmdate('m.d.y',$row['idate'])."</span>";
                     echo "<a href='view.php?id=".$row['id']."'<span class='title'>".$row['title']."</span></a>";
                     echo "<br>";
                     echo "<span class='announce'>".$row['announce']."</span>";
                     echo "<br>";
                  }
                     mysqli_free_result($result);
           }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <strong><p id="page"> Страницы:</p></strong>

    <?php
    //Вывожу кнопки-ссылки на другие страницы
         $num_rows=0;
            if ($result=mysqli_query($link,'SELECT*FROM news'))
                 {
                    $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                     mysqli_free_result($result);
                 }
            mysqli_close($link);

            for ($x=1;$x<=($num_rows)/5+1;$x++)
                 echo "<div  class='foot' id='".$x."'><a href='?page=".$x."' class='col' style='text-decoration:none;color:black'>".$x."</a></div>"
    ?>
  
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.col').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');

    })

})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```